# Operate in gnuplot

Tags: dataset, gnuplot, data-manipulation, derivative

Let's assume a data file with two rows like this one

```
x   y
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
```

Using gnuplot, I want to plot the first derivative `y'`. In a first aproximation,

[image: latex equation]

In Excel this is simple to make, however I don't know how to do it in gnuplot (I don't know if it's possible).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/15751226/7295599

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I plot the derivative of a graph in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751226/how-can-i-plot-the-derivative-of-a-graph-in-gnuplot)